# Writting in a text file with JS

Tags: javascript, text-files

I basically need to write in a text file with JS,
but like when i write on it i want it to go on the next line and write smth, not overwriting the old text.

How it shouldn't be :
file before changing w script

```
ENTER TEXT HERE
```

file after changing w script

```
AISDIJAISJIASJD
```

.
.
.

How it should be :

file before changing w script

```
ENTER TEXT HERE
```

file after changing w script

```
ENTER TEXT HERE
KNdANANSNDASDKL
```

Comment: Do you use `node.js`? How do you write file?

Comment: Yeah i do use node.js

I just want a JS script to write a text file, but when we write i want it to write on the next line and not overwritting the old text.

Comment: You have to open a file with `append` flag

Comment: Could you write it for me..? I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use nodejs [appendFile](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-appendfile-function/)

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.appendFileSync('file.txt', 'adasdasd\n');
```